# Bug in gdb libstdc++ pretty-printers with gcc 8 installed from macports (macOS)

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, macports, libstdc++

I set up gdb libstdc++ pretty-printers as described in [GDB Wiki](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport). But pretty printing didn't work, gdb kept printing raw data.

I changed *printers.py* to fix it:

```
--- python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py.old 2018-10-13 13:57:11.000000000 +0300
+++ python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py 2018-10-13 14:35:55.000000000 +0300
@@ -1306,2 +1306,4 @@
     def add(self, name, function):
+        if (name.startswith('std::')):
+            self.add(name[5:], function)
         # A small sanity check.
```

The patch makes Printer handle std::xxx and xxx equally (e.g. std::vector and vector). The patch helped!

Why did it help? Where is the bug? Used gdb 8.0.1, gcc 8.2.0 installed via macports.

Comment: _"I set up gdb libstdc++ pretty-printers as described in GDB Wiki."_ What exactly did you do? Most of that info is outdated and should be unnecessary with modern versions of GDB and GCC, because the printers already come with GCC.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but using `-gdwarf-3` instead of just `-g`, `whatis $vector` for a vector of double correctly shows `std::vector<double>` instead of `vector<double, std::allocator<double> >`. According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html, `-g` defaults to `-gdwarf-2` on macOS. However I don't know how the DWARF level influences the types known to GDB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52792439/981959) on OS X but I'm unable to debug it myself, as I don't use OS X.

The problem seems to be related to the debug info that GCC outputs into OS X binaries. On OS X the types shown in the debug info do not match what the pretty printers expect.